# Centering author name in Beamer and repositioning the date

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I'm doing a presentation on beamer. I have two author names. I want them centered and display on separate lines. Also I want the date to be on lower part centered. Currently all of them are left aligned. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{beaver}


\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author{Author A \and Author B }
\vspace{3pt}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove the `\vspace{3pt}` from your preamble, it won't do anything there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could patch the beamer templates used in the title page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Author A\\ Author B }
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{date}{\centering}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@title}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{author}{\centering}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use the `moloch` theme, a more up-to-date fork of the metropolis theme, you can use a similar approach:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Author A\\ Author B }
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{date}{\centering}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@title}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@author}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you replace

```
\author{Author A \and Author B }
\vspace{3pt}
\date{\today}
```

with

```
\author{\centering Author A \\ Author B}
\vspace{3pt}
\date{\centering\today}
```

Just out of idle curiosity: Why don't you want the title centered as well? Having the title left-aligned, but the authors and date centered, looks a bit odd.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author{\centering Author A \\ Author B}
\vspace{3pt}
\date{\centering\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To center the title string as well, I suggest you change

```
\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
```

to

```
\title[About Beamer]{\hspace{\fill}Graph Representation Techniques\hspace*{\fill}}
```

Note that this works for title strings that fit on one line. I trust this isn't much of a constraint in practice: Titles of beamer presentations always "work" best if they're short -- the shorter, the better!

The resulting title page (document compiled with XeLaTeX) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add how to center the title as well? Also, running this code on sharelatex produces some errors. Is it normal?
Image link: https://imgur.com/a/qKNvvS7

Comment: @Robur_131 - I'll edit my answer to show how to center the title as well. About the error messages: Did you compile the sample document under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? The reason I ask is that the `metropolis` theme says that it wants to be compiled under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Currently the compiler is showing pdfLatex.

Comment: @Robur_131 - Did you notice the following warning message in the log file, if the document is compiled under pdflatex: "Package beamerthememetropolis Warning: You need to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to use the Fira fonts on input line 95." I guess one *can* use the `metropolis` theme with pdflatex, but one won't get the Fira fonts for which this theme was designed.

Comment: @Robur_131 - The version of the `beamer` package that's installed on my system is `beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50`. What does the log file say about the version of `beamer` that's on ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Document Class: beamer 2017/01/23 v3.41

Comment: @Robur_131 - Wow, that's positively ancient, by software standards. Any chance you can find a more up-to-date system to compile your document?